# PHP giving specific item access to admins

Tags: php, sql

So I have this food ordering system where each admin uploads his or her food from the backend and users can browse through those food from the frontend, a simple program. But what I want is that an admin should not be able to view or update the food from another admin as right now any of the admins can view and update all the food that are uploaded on the backend. What I want is only a specific admin only viewing and updating his or her added food items.
Attached below is the snippet and picture of the food view and update page where it displays all foods and can update them.
FYI the code is in PHP and the backend is SQL in phpMyAdmin
Please do let me if there are any confusions in my explanation.

```
<?php include('partials/menu.php'); ?>

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Manage Food</h1>

        <br /><br />

                <!-- Button to Add Admin -->
                <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/add-food.php" class="btn-primary">Add Food</a>

                <br /><br /><br />

                <?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['add']))
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['add'];
                        unset($_SESSION['add']);
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['delete']))
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['delete'];
                        unset($_SESSION['delete']);
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['upload']))
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['upload'];
                        unset($_SESSION['upload']);
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['unauthorize']))
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['unauthorize'];
                        unset($_SESSION['unauthorize']);
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['update']))
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['update'];
                        unset($_SESSION['update']);
                    }
                
                ?>

                <table class="tbl-full">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.N.</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Featured</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php 
                        //Create a SQL Query to Get all the Food
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_food";

                        //Execute the qUery
                        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                        //Count Rows to check whether we have foods or not
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

                        //Create Serial Number VAriable and Set Default VAlue as 1
                        $sn=1;

                        if($count>0)
                        {
                            //We have food in Database
                            //Get the Foods from Database and Display
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                            {
                                //get the values from individual columns
                                $id = $row['id'];
                                $title = $row['title'];
                                $price = $row['price'];
                                $image_name = $row['image_name'];
                                $featured = $row['featured'];
                                $active = $row['active'];
                                ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $sn++; ?>. </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
                                    <td>$<?php echo $price; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php  
                                            //CHeck whether we have image or not
                                            if($image_name=="")
                                            {
                                                //WE do not have image, DIslpay Error Message
                                                echo "<div class='error'>Image not Added.</div>";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //WE Have Image, Display Image
                                                ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>images/food/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" width="100px">
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $featured; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $active; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/update-food.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn-secondary">Update Food</a>
                                        <a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>admin/delete-food.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&image_name=<?php echo $image_name; ?>" class="btn-danger">Delete Food</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Food not Added in Database
                            echo "<tr> <td colspan='7' class='error'> Food not Added Yet. </td> </tr>";
                        }

                    ?>

                    
                </table>
    </div>
    
</div>

<?php include('partials/footer.php'); ?>
```

Attached is a picture of this
[image: Here]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a new column in the table tbl_food

Actual clumns:

```
//get the values from individual columns
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$price = $row['price'];
$image_name = $row['image_name'];
$featured = $row['featured'];
$active = $row['active'];
```

Add a column "**owned_by**" with the **admin_ID** of the user that added that food.

Step 1. (that's MySQL, but you can adapt to your DB)

```
alter table tbl_food add owned_by int;
```

Step 2.
when some admin add a food, you add this ID value in the insert, with others food information.

Step 3.
When some admin update the food, you check if this food is owned by this admin, and in update query you add

```
[..]and owned_by = admin_ID;
```

To accomplish this, you need that any admin has his own ID or email or access token
If all the admins are sharing the same account to upload the food, before of what I said you need to add a multiuser control access system.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out, i will try this and if anything will let you know

Comment: Hi Daniele.. should i put the code .." alter table tbl_food add owned_by int;" that you gave  under  "$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_food"; ?

Comment: Hi, no, it's not a code that you put in PHP. 
It's about DB design, to be executed on the DB!

Comment: now my program works a bit but the code u sent [..]and owned_by = admin_ID;..may i know wheer to put this?..should it be in the manage-food code that i sent above or in the updates one?

Comment: also i think it would be better if starting from the food view page only those items are shown to the admin which are associated with their id so form the above code may i nkow how to do that as by doing that it will be really easy as only the food that the admin is associated with will come and from there he canupdate edit as he likes..dont have to make changes inthe update codes thats y simple..i already added a owned by in my tbl_food may i know now what do i have to do..Sorry for disturbing, its just that i dont have much knowledge on php and sql and am learning

Comment: Ok, if you did the step 1, you should go on with step 2. "Step 2. when some admin add a food, you add this ID value in the insert, with others food information."